# follow webpack tutorial but failed to bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

i follow the tutorial strictly to type webpack cmd.

> ./node_modules/.bin/webpack src/index.js dist/bundle.js

but it shows error

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command then i tried

---

then i tried

> node_modules/.bin/webpack src/index.js dist/bundle.js

still fail

> node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command

then i have to use global webpack, it can work, but without bundle lodash.js
can anyone help?

Comment: Please post your config and the command you are using to initialise webpack

Comment: `./node_modules/.bin/webpack `  is the command, but the problem is that windows cannot recognize the directory to access webpack commond.

Comment: Try adding `"build": "webpack src/index.js dist/bundle.js"` to your `scripts` in `package.json`. Make sure you have `webpack` installed as a dependency.

Comment: i found the reason already. windows cmp prompt doesn't recognize the directory with './' such as "./node_modules", has to use Bash